# How to check if a value isn't changed in between <span> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

The page looks like:

```
<html>
  <span id="somespan">1000</span>
</html>
```

The value of somespan increases every 1 or 2 minutes.

With Javascript/JQuery, how can I check if the value is same or increased every 5 minutes.

I mean at 16:00 the value is 1000 and 2 minutes later so at 16:02 its 1200.
How can I check if its changed.

I wanna make something like:

```
var somespan = $("#somespan").text();

if(somespan isnt changed) {
  #console.log('still same.')    
}
```

The platform i will use this code is Google Chrome -> Tampermonkey

Comment: You can use DOMSubtreeModified as $('#somespan').on('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
   alert('Value changed')
 })

Comment: Do you have control over the the code that changes the span in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), but this will do as well.

```js
var current_value = null;
setInterval( function() {
  if (current_value != null) {
    if (current_value != $('#somespan').text()) {
      console.log('Value has changed!');
    }
  }
  current_value = $('#somespan').text();
}, 1000 );

// For testing only
$('input').on('input', function() {
  $('#somespan').text( $(this).val() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="somespan">1000</span>

<!-- For testing only -->
<br/>
<input type="text" value="1000">
```

#### via MutationObserver (no polling required)

```js
const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  for (const mutation of mutations) {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
      console.log('Value has changed!')
    }
  }
});

observer.observe(document.querySelector('#somespan'), {childList: true});

// For testing only
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function() {
  document.querySelector('#somespan').innerHTML = this.value;
});
```

```html
<span id="somespan">1000</span>

<!-- For testing only -->
<br/>
<input type="text" value="1000">
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

How about a mini-array? To hold the prev value and reset with every new value added.

```
// Global Variables
var somespan = document.getElementById("somespan");
// Global Variables => Array Values
var somespan_arr = [];

// Interval / Time function to check if # changed every 5 seconds
setInterval(function(){
  somespan_arr.push(somespan.innerHTML); // Push the initial value into array
  if (somespan.innerHTML != somespan_arr[0]) { // Check if prev value is different
    somespan_arr = []; // Reset Array back to default or ""
    somespan_arr.push(somespan.innerHTML); // Push new value
    console.log("Doesn't Match!"); // Logging Results
    console.log(somespan_arr); // Logging Results
  } else {
    console.log("It matches!"); // Logging Results
  }
},5000); // 5000 => 5 seconds where 1000 = 1 second
```

Please excuse any mistakes made, I am very new to Stackoverflow.